# How to prove these properties of vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector subspace of $R^n$, $v_0$ a vector in $R^n$, and $F = v_0 + V = {\{v_o + v : v \in V}\}$.
Prove that the following are equivalent, i.e. if one of them holds, they all hold.

a) $F$ is a subspace of $R^n$

b) $ v_0 \in V$

c) $F=V$

If I take b) to be true, then $v_0 + v \in V$ since $V$ is a subspace and thus closed under addition. Then $F=V$ as adding $v_0$ to $V$ does not change $V$, since $v_0$ was already an element in $V$.

Is this correct? Am I on the right track? Where would I go from here?

Comment: Yes, you are. a) says that $F$ is a subspace, and you've just shown that $F=V$, which is a subspace by assumption, so $F$ is a ...?

Comment: I think what I've shown so far is that F is a subset of V, but don't believe I can make the assumption that F = V as I haven't proven that V is a subset of F...

Comment: Could I assume c) to be true, and from that conclude that $v_0=0$? Then $v_0 \in V$ as the zero vector is in every subspace, and F=V with V a subspace, so clearly F is a subspace as well... Is this a correct solution?

Comment: c) doesn't imply $v_0 = 0$, it only implies $v_0 \in V$, but you don't need this.

Answer (score 3):

$a) \Rightarrow b)$

If $F$ is a subspace, then $ 0 \in F$. Since $V$ is a subspace, $-v_0 + F = V$ implies that $- v_0 = -v_0 + 0 \in V$, thus $v_0 \in V$.

$b) \Rightarrow c) $

What you said is correct.

$c) \Rightarrow a)$

If $V$ is a subspace and $F = V$, then $F$ is also a subspace. (Since it is the exact same object, with the exact same properties as $V$.)